# Tika empty result

Tags: java, apache-tika, lucee

I am working with the Tika Java library. I'm using Lucee (a sub part of ColdFusion) and when I use an online example to retrieve text from a PDF I get an empty string.

### What is the setup?

I've installed Lucee locally and have access to an empty index.cfm page. I've added the Tika jar file to the project and I see it's loaded correctly in the Lucee admin.

### What is the code?

The following part is the most simple code I could find to convert a PDF to text:

```
    handler = createObject("java", "org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler");
    metadata = createObject("java", "org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata");
    inputstream = createObject("java", "java.io.FileInputStream").init(createObject("java", "java.io.File").init('C:\lucee\tomcat\webapps\ROOT\test\dummy.pdf'));   
    pcontext = createObject("java", "org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext");
    pdfparser = createObject("java", "org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser");
    pdfparser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata, pcontext);
    writeDump(handler.toString());
```

so when I run this I get an empty string and I expect the text inside the PDF. Also all the metadata is empty.

### Conclusion

I think that the library is perhaps not loaded correctly. But what can I do to see where this is going wrong? I don't get any error, just empty values. Tried different PDFs and even different files. Tried the autoparser and different kind of codes. Is this maybe a Lucee problem? Or a Java problem?

Comment: You should follow the [Apache Tika troubleshooting guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/Troubleshooting+Tika#TroubleshootingTika-NoContentExtracted) - sounds like you're missing dependency jars but the guide will take you through the steps to be sure!

Comment: I was trying but I'm using Lucee (working on JAVA) instead of clean JAVA. So I don't really have a console to test the dependencies. But I will try to check it in a different way. Thanks for you answer!

Comment: It has been a very long time since I worked with ColdFusion, but I seem to recall there used to be some sort of admin interface where you could see all the jars you were using.

Comment: Indeed, and as I stated in the thread lucee tells me it is correctly loaded, but doesn't really look like it.

Comment: The Tika Core jar != all of Tika - you need to add more than just one jar!